# Prepare Statement with LIKE in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, prepared-statement

Greeting of the day !!

It is a raw query in laravel 5.1.

```
 $select = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM `grids` INNER JOIN masters ON 
        grids.q_id=masters.q_id LEFT JOIN qrs ON qrs.qr_id= masters.qr_id
         AND qrs.mi_cd = grids.mi_cd WHERE grids.mi_cd='ZZ' 
         AND substr(grids.q_id,1,3)='".$user->id."' 
         AND grids.q_id LIKE '___".trim(":year")."%' AND qrs.submitted=1"),
      [':year'=>'$year']
      );
```

My problem is if I use prepare statement with like in laravel raw query then data is not found if I use without prepare statement then it  will be sql injected.
There is any way, prepare statement with like, in Laravel raw query???

Comment: any particular reason you are using only `DB::raw`? This query can be easily done with the Query Builder for most parts of it like `->where` and `->join`? etc.

Comment: some times query will be complex then I do have only one solution raw query. My question is There is any way, prepare statement with like, in Laravel raw query???

Comment: `->where('grids.q_id', 'like',  '___' . trim($year) . '%')`

Comment: Laravel Query Builder takes care of SQL injection itself, except when using `DB::raw()`.

Comment: Maybe this helps:

   `DB::table('grids')
    ->select('*')->
    ->leftJoin('masters', 'grids.q_id', '=', 'masters.q_id')
    ->leftJoin('qrs', function($join) {
        $join->on('qrs.qr_id', '=', 'masters.qr_id')
            ->where('qrs.mi_cd', '=', 'grids.mi_cd')
    })
    ->where('grids.mi_cd', '=', 'ZZ')
    ->where('substr(grids.q_id,1,3)', '=', $user->id)
    ->where('grids.q_id', 'like', '___' . trim($year) . '%')
    ->where('qrs.submitted', '=', 1);`

Comment: @CodeLove did you find the solution?